# empty reportviewer parameter

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I have designed a report (.rdl file) that has a parameter and I am setting that parameter in .net c# and passing to the reportviewer. How would you handle a report where the parameter is not set to a value. I would like to return all rows if the parameter is null.

This is what I have in the report designer:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Users
WHERE UserID = (@ReportParameter1)
```

Answer (score 0):

change the Select as:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Users
WHERE UserID = (@ReportParameter1) or @ReportParameter1 is null
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Incorrect syntax near '='.` when I run the application

Comment: your report is a rdl or rdlc(is on SSRS or is local)?

Comment: the report is rdl and local

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Users
where (@ReportParameter1 is null or UserID =@ReportParameter1)
```

Comment: I did set that value to true. The values I am using are from a dropdown and now this is the error I am getting: `The value provided for the report parameter 'ReportParameter1' is not valid for its type. ` when I select an empty item.